# How to create loop for Data Frame only by existing combinations and only one time for combination in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

Hellow! I have DataFrame like below:

```
e = pd.DataFrame()
e["val1"] = [10, 20, 10]
e["val2"] = [1, 2, 1]
```

and Data Frame with unique combinations of values from DF "e":

```
e_unique = e.groupby(['val1','val2']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
e_unique.drop(columns=["count"], inplace=True)
```

How can I create loop (base on uniqe combo present in "e_unique" DF) so as to iterate for DF "e" but only by existing combinations and each combinations need to be only one time, so I need result of loop like below:

```
10 1 
20 2
```

NOT for instance like below !!!!!! :) Because When I use for example code like below I have result like below and it is wrong, because each EXISTING combo I need only one time (each existing combo are in e_unique DF above:

```
for v1, v2 in zip(e["val1"], e["val2"]):
    print(v1, v2)

10 1 
20 2
10 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to build a list and transform it into a set to remove the duplicates.

```
for pair in set([(v1, v2) for v1, v2 in zip(e['val1'], e['val2'])]):
    print (pair)
```

Comment: Ok, but how to present result not in tuple ?

Comment: Or how to separate pair to two separeted columns ?

Comment: What is your intended presentation form? You can access elements in tuple using the index: pair[0], pair[1].